# filtering and search with Regex C#

Tags: regex, search, filter

I want to write a command that shows me, for example, "this" **to** "that", everything that appears between these two words.

Example: "From my **university** to my friend's **house** is 20 miles away."

Filter = "**university**" and "**house**".

Result = "**to my friend's**"

That will show me the result.

**Please Help Me.** I need this code.

> I think Regex can write this command, but I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for this is

`university(.*)house`

You can see this in action [here](https://regexr.com/3v4sa).

The `.` is a wildcard, and the `*` tells us the wildcard character can be matched multiple times. The `()` creates a group, where the contents of the group can be matched later on. Since this group is between the words university and house, and because we told this group to match any character, the result will be everything between the words university and house.

In C# You'll need to import regular expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

And then you can grab all of the regex matches:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"university(.*)house",
          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string example = "From my university to my friend's house is 20 miles away.";

MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine("Match: {0} at index [{1}, {2})", 
        match.Value, 
        match.Index, 
        match.Index + match.Length);
}
```

Comment: There is a problem here. If my text is: "20 miles from the **university** to my friend's **house**. It is 20 miles from the **university** to the Aunt **house**. It is 20 miles from the **university** to the uncle's **house**".  The result is: **to my friend's**, **to the Aunt** , **to the uncle's**.  I want to search the whole text and show me all the words between the two words.(university,house)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following RegEx:

```
(?<=university).+(?=house)
```

if your RegEx supports lookbehind and look forward.

It looks behind to find `university`, then selects all characters up to `house`. Given your example it gives the correct result: `to my friend's`.

You can of course change the search Words, making a formula that Works for every search Words:

```
string word1 = "university";
string word2 = "house";
string sentence = "From my university to my friend's house is 20 miles away.";
RegEx reEx = new RegEx("(<=" + word1 + ").+(?" + word2 + ")");
string match = regex.Match(sentence).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here.

If my text is: "20 miles from the **university** to my friend's **house**. It is 20 miles from the **university** to the Aunt **house**. It is 20 miles from the **university** to the uncle's **house**"

The result is: **to my friend's**, **to the Aunt** , **to the uncle's**

I want to search the whole text and show me all the words between the two words.(university,house)